# SQL NOT EXISTS - inserting without duplicates

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 tables, with different field names, but same data. I want to Import into one table the data from the other table without generating duplicate rows.

This is what I tried (I'm working in Access VBA) :

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

Dim SQL As String

SQL = "INSERT INTO COMPANY(CompanyNumber, CompanyName)" & _
            " SELECT Number, Company" & _
            " FROM NEW" & _
            " WHERE NOT EXISTS " & _
            "(SELECT CompanyNumber, CompanyName FROM COMPANY)" 

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

This is returning me to append 0 rows. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` must contain a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Language fixes, reformat code

Comment: Do you have a primary key in tableA?

Comment: What do you mean by 'duplicate rows'? duplicate primary key/ unique key, or the whole row the same?

Comment: Only table that needs to be inserted to has unique key. Second table is just an Excel spreadsheet that has two columns. Data is Company Number and Company Name. Each Company Number has It's Company Name, so these 2 have to be same, without importing duplicates.

Comment: mysql is not ms-access. Please edit your tags to reach the right peaple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesssss, I have finally managed It to work, It was a whole day nightmare. Here It is:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

Dim SQL As String

SQL = "INSERT INTO COMPANY(CompanyNumber, CompanyName)" & _
            " SELECT DISTINCT Number, Company" & _
            " FROM NEW" & _
            " WHERE NOT EXISTS " & _
            "(SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE" & _
            " (NEW.Number=COMPANY.CompanyNumber AND NEW.Company=COMPANY.CompanyName)" 

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

@DylanSue thanks, all to all others, you helped me a lot. Looks like MS-access is quite strange when doing duplicates. I added `DISTINCT` because second table has many same entries. However, If I execute same code twice, It imports again 2 rows - one of them is empty on both columns and one only in one column. How can I avoid of blank entries for both columns ?? (If one column is blank, then It should import also).

Comment: I have, but It's still not working. I had to use IS NULL instead of ' ', but when I do that and run code twice, SQL still Imports one row where 1 column is blank and other is not. But If I use another AND NOT for both cases where 1 column is blank, then import of that row doesn't happen in first case too...

Comment: You mean when you ran query twice, you didnt import nothing if one column is blank and other not ?

Comment: I meant I didn't understant ur situation. But now I get it and I updated my ans with a new solution, with more handling for NULLs values. Pls try.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index on the table (table_1) where you want to insert all columns that must be unique. Then execute this. The Name of the columns are not important, but the order of the fields must be the same. If not you must specify the order of the columns in Table 2. Change * to fieldname1,fieldname3,fieldname2,...

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_1
  SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

Comment: Ňot working. I have unique key for records on first table, and not in second - It just an Excel spreadsheet. I also tried this : INSERT IGNORE INTO TableA (AField1,AField2)" & _
  "SELECT * FROM TableB (BField1, BField2);"

Comment: Let me say once more. TableA has 3 columns - ID_Number, Company Number and Company Name - in same order. TableB has only two columns - Company Number and Company Name, in same order - no ID in this one, It's just an Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Since with MS-ACCESS, the solution become more complicated.

Moreover, to handle NULLs well, more filters are added. For NULL,NULL row, it will not be inserted into TableA, while xx, NULL will be inserted.

For short, the required INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement is like:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(Company_Number, Company_Name)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Company_Number, Company_Name
FROM
    TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 
                1
             FROM 
                TableA
             WHERE
                (TableA.Company_Number=TableB.Company_Number OR (TableA.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Number IS NULL)) AND 
                (TableA.Company_Name=TableB.Company_Name OR (TableA.Company_Name IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL)) AND
                NOT (TableB.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL));
```

A complete demo is attached.(I have no environment for MS-ACCESS, and this is executed in MySQL 5.7).

SQL:

```
create table TableA(ID_Number int auto_increment primary key, Company_Number int, Company_Name varchar(200));
create table TableB(Company_Number int, Company_Name varchar(200));

insert into TableA(Company_Number, Company_Name) values
(1,'A'),
(2,'B');
insert into TableB(Company_Number, Company_Name) values
(2,'B'),
(3,'C'),
(4,NULL),
(NULL,'D');
SELECT * FROM TableA;
SELECT * FROM TableB;
INSERT INTO TableA(Company_Number, Company_Name)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Company_Number, Company_Name
FROM
    TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 
                1
             FROM 
                TableA
             WHERE
                (TableA.Company_Number=TableB.Company_Number OR (TableA.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Number IS NULL)) AND 
                (TableA.Company_Name=TableB.Company_Name OR (TableA.Company_Name IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL)) AND
                NOT (TableB.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL));
SELECT * FROM TableA;

INSERT INTO TableA(Company_Number, Company_Name)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Company_Number, Company_Name
FROM
    TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 
                1
             FROM 
                TableA
             WHERE
                (TableA.Company_Number=TableB.Company_Number OR (TableA.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Number IS NULL)) AND 
                (TableA.Company_Name=TableB.Company_Name OR (TableA.Company_Name IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL)) AND
                NOT (TableB.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL));
SELECT * FROM TableA;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM TableA;
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| ID_Number | Company_Number | Company_Name |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
|         1 |              1 | A            |
|         2 |              2 | B            |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM TableB;
+----------------+--------------+
| Company_Number | Company_Name |
+----------------+--------------+
|              2 | B            |
|              3 | C            |
|              4 | NULL         |
|           NULL | D            |
+----------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO TableA(Company_Number, Company_Name)
    -> SELECT
    ->     DISTINCT Company_Number, Company_Name
    -> FROM
    ->     TableB
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ->             (SELECT
    ->                 1
    ->              FROM
    ->                 TableA
    ->              WHERE
    ->                 (TableA.Company_Number=TableB.Company_Number OR (TableA.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Number IS NULL)) AND
    ->                 (TableA.Company_Name=TableB.Company_Name OR (TableA.Company_Name IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL)) AND
    ->                 NOT (TableB.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL));
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM TableA;
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| ID_Number | Company_Number | Company_Name |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
|         1 |              1 | A            |
|         2 |              2 | B            |
|         3 |              3 | C            |
|         4 |              4 | NULL         |
|         5 |           NULL | D            |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> INSERT INTO TableA(Company_Number, Company_Name)
    -> SELECT
    ->     DISTINCT Company_Number, Company_Name
    -> FROM
    ->     TableB
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ->             (SELECT
    ->                 1
    ->              FROM
    ->                 TableA
    ->              WHERE
    ->                 (TableA.Company_Number=TableB.Company_Number OR (TableA.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Number IS NULL)) AND
    ->                 (TableA.Company_Name=TableB.Company_Name OR (TableA.Company_Name IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL)) AND
    ->                 NOT (TableB.Company_Number IS NULL AND TableB.Company_Name IS NULL));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM TableA;
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| ID_Number | Company_Number | Company_Name |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
|         1 |              1 | A            |
|         2 |              2 | B            |
|         3 |              3 | C            |
|         4 |              4 | NULL         |
|         5 |           NULL | D            |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This would be the same as `INSERT IGNORE` and a unique key must be defined.

Comment: I tried that too, not working, syntax error in WHERE clause.

Comment: There is no WHERE clause in this statement.

Comment: @DylanSu, I'm sorry, I receive error in FROM clause. This is what I tried : ˙"INSERT INTO TableA(AField1,AField2)" & _
" SELECT BField1, Bfield2" & _
" FROM TableB" & _
"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE AField2=AField2;"˙

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 Finally get ur meaning now. Updated the post. Pls try again.

Comment: @DylanSu, I tried, but I receive this error(3306): " You have written a subquery that can return more than one field witout using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field". How can I paste my exact code, in same way as I posted In first post ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 I am not quite sure about your situation now. I updated the post with a full demo. Please check if anything I use is wrong.

Comment: @DylanSu, I'm not quite sure about mySQL as I'm working with MS-ACCESS, but in first look you have exactly same construct of tables as mine. But It's not working in MS -ACCESS. And I have just found on one forum that IN(SELECT) clause can return only one field. See this link, post no.4 : http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/microsoft-access-error-3306.2808252/

Comment: I thought u r using MySQL. Updated, try again. @LuckyLuke82

Comment: @DylanSu, this is nightmare, nothing is working, whatever I try. Is there any option here that I can post like a normal code, maybe there is some synthax problems with VBA. I keep receiving this error : "Synthax error in query expression".

Comment: If u want to post like normal code, you need to paste into ur question, or in a answer post. u can't do it comment. I am not familiar with MS-ACCESS.

Comment: Ok, see It now, in my question, maybe you'll figure out what is wrong. Notice that field names are not same in both tables.

Comment: my bad. Remove the last "SELECT * FROM COMPANY". It was added by mistake just now.

Comment: I allready tried this before. but I'm still receiving same synthax error, bump. Looks like somebody with VBA experience has to tell me how to manage this, It's driving me nuts.

Comment: @DylanSu, are you still here ? I managed to fix Import, but now I'm facing another issue. Second table has also multiple rows for same Company (first and second column same data multiple time), but I want to Import rows only once for each company. How can I do that ??

Comment: Updated and added a Distinct. Btw how did u fixed the import?

Comment: See my answer @DylanSu. I appreciated all your help, really.

Comment: @DylanSu, If you are still here, read my post under my answer.

Comment: @DylanSue, thanks for answer, looks like this one should do correct Import. I was away so I couldn't answer you, I will try this and let you know. Thanks again !!

Comment: @DylanSu, I tested now. It's not working. First of all, code runs very slow, and It inserts row where both columns are empty. Second, It still wants to import 1 row when code is launched again. Acess is really behaving badly on this matter. I'll try to figure out something else, or I'll just stick to my answer and try to somehow prevent user for running same import tiwce. Thanks for all your efforts though, you really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason don't want to create a unique key on (AField1, AField2) you just need to add `SELECT 1 FROM TablA WHERE` into your `NOT EXISTS` part:

```sql
INSERT INTO TableA (AField1, AField2)
    SELECT BField1,Bfield2
    FROM TableB
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM TableA
        WHERE TableB.BField1 = TableA.AField1 AND TableB.BField2 = TableA.AField2
    )
```

You can also try an excluding LEFT JOIN:

```sql
INSERT INTO TableA (AField1, AField2)
    SELECT BField1,Bfield2
    FROM TableB
    LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.BField1 = TableA.AField1 AND TableB.BField2 = TableA.AField2
    WHERE TableA.AField1 IS NULL
```

Comment: To answer to Paul Spiegel - I have tried this too before, not working : "INSERT INTO TableA (AField1, AField2)" & _
"SELECT BField1,Bfield2" & _
"FROM TableB" & _
"WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE (TableB.BField1 = TableA.AField1 AND TableB.BField2 = TableA.AField2))"

Comment: It works for me and works for [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14cb9/2). What do you mean by "not working"? Are duplicate rows inserted?